# When unit testing with Jasmine, how to require a file without 'sub-requires'?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

let's say in my spec I write the follow,

```
const moduleA = require('moduleA');
```

... and in moduleA it will require another module say 'moduleB'

In my opinion unit testing should be separate, and all dependencies should be mocked. But I can't find a good way to require moduleA without requiring moduleB at the same time.

Any suggestions how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Things I've tried:
rewirejs(https://github.com/jhnns/rewire), which seems nice but still needs to require moduleB before you can actually substitute moduleB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your modules export a function that will take the dependency as an argument (instead of requiring it). So you'll have:

```
/*moduleA*/
module.export = function(depB){
    /*your code here*/
});
```

And when you import `moduleA` you do:

```
var moduleB = require('moduleB');
var moduleA = require('moduleA')(moduleB);
```

An alternative approach would be to pass a dependency tree to the submodule:

```
const platform = {
     moduleA : require('moduleA'),
     moduleB : require('moduleB'),
}

var moduleA = platform.moduleA(platform);
```

And in `moduleA`:

```
module.export = function(platform){
    var moduleB = platform.moduleB; //your dependency here
    //for consistency you'd also want to export a function that takes the depdency tree even if it doesnt take a dependency (so module configuration remains consistent across all your modules)
}
```

It would be very easy to replace the dependency for a mock this way. There is more on the subject [here](https://gbracha.blogspot.com/2009/06/ban-on-imports.html) and [here](https://awelonblue.wordpress.com/2011/09/29/modularity-without-a-name/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in my project one file actually requires a lot of dependencies, so requiring moduleA will become require('moduleA')(moduleB, moduleC, moduleD, moduleE ...), which is kind of clumsy in my situation.

Comment: I recommend the second approach then, it's on the last link i put. I'll put an example.